# store data persistent for learn app with unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a language learn app with unity. I want to implement that when you guessed a work (e.g. a number) incorrect, you need to guess the word again in the next iteration. I thought of a way that you store for each word in every play mode a value between +10 to -10 and when an item has a big negative number the word occurrence more often than if it has a big positiv number.

My Problem is that I don't know how to store the data properly. PlayerPrefs are too inconvenient for this problem, and I don't know how to modify a JSON file properly.

Currently, I store the data for the items in a class.
[image]

Maybe you could have a structure like:

```
Numbers
   write
     zero: -5
     one: +3
   match
     zero: +5
     one: +4
Alphabet
   write:
     A: -10
   match: 
     A: +5
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best JSON serialization libraries is [Newtonsoft.Json](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity).

You can use your class and serialize an object to JSON object, and then save it as a string to file.

```
public static string Serialize(object obj)
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
}
```

After that you can save it to file in the [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) directory.

```
var text = Serialize(data);

var tmpFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "filename");
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(tmpFilePath));
if (File.Exists(tmpFilePath))
{
    File.Delete(tmpFilePath);
}
File.WriteAllText(tmpFilePath, text);
```

After that you can read the file at any time using [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-6.0) and deserialize it to an object.

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string text)
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };
    
    try
    {
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(text, settings);
        return result ?? default;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e);
    }
    return default;
}
```

```
T result = default;
try
{
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(path);
        result = Deserialize<T>(text);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.LogException(e);
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to store data persistently between play sessions in Unity. `PlayerPrefs` and creating your own JSON file are the simplest ways of doing this.
The good news is that JSON files are quite easy to make and modify, thanks to the builtin [JSONUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) Unity provides.

If you make a separate class or struct to hold your scores, give that clas a `[Serializable]` tag and keep a reference to that in your current setup (which is probably a `MonoBehaviour`).

You can use the [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-6.0) class (specifically [File.CreateText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.opentext?view=net-6.0) and [File.OpenText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.opentext?view=net-6.0)) to write to/read from a file. If you do this every time a value changes, you should end up with persistent saved data across multiple play sessions.